# MD5 not giving correct hash for online file in iOS

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, md5

I really don't know how it is possible but I am checking two files for their MD5 hashes, so I can determine if they are the same or not.

The problem is that the local file (the file stored in the app bundle) gives the correct value and the one stored on online server is giving bad value. However, if I check the md5 of the online file in Terminal on Mac, or by some internet tool, it gives the correct value.

How is this possible?

This is basically what I am doing.

```
NSData *currencyData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.iworldtip.com/appl/texts/files/CountryCurrency.plist"]];
NSData *localCurrencyData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"CountryCurrency" ofType:@"plist"]];

NSString *currencyDataHashValue = [currencyData md5];
NSString *localCurrencyDataHashValue = [localCurrencyData md5];

if (![currencyDataHashValue isEqual:localCurrencyDataHashValue]) {
            NSLog(@"Saving new version of currency plist\n\n%@ - %@", currencyDataHashValue, localCurrencyDataHashValue);
...
...
```

Here is the output:

[image]

---

This is the md5 extension which I am using (found somewhere online):

.h file:

```
@interface NSString (MyExtensions)
- (NSString *) md5;
@end

@interface NSData (MyExtensions)
- (NSString*)md5;
@end
```

.m file:

```
#import "md5Extension.h"
#import <CommonCrypto/CommonDigest.h>

@implementation NSString (MyExtensions)
- (NSString *) md5
{
    const char *cStr = [self UTF8String];
    unsigned char result[16];
    CC_MD5( cStr, strlen(cStr), result ); // This is the md5 call
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:
            @"%02x%02x%02x%02x%02x%02x%02x%02x%02x%02x%02x%02x%02x%02x%02x%02x",
            result[0], result[1], result[2], result[3], 
            result[4], result[5], result[6], result[7],
            result[8], result[9], result[10], result[11],
            result[12], result[13], result[14], result[15]
            ];  
}
@end

@implementation NSData (MyExtensions)
- (NSString*)md5
{
    unsigned char result[16];
    CC_MD5( self.bytes, self.length, result ); // This is the md5 call
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:
            @"%02x%02x%02x%02x%02x%02x%02x%02x%02x%02x%02x%02x%02x%02x%02x%02x",
            result[0], result[1], result[2], result[3], 
            result[4], result[5], result[6], result[7],
            result[8], result[9], result[10], result[11],
            result[12], result[13], result[14], result[15]
            ];  
}
@end
```

Comment: Have you tried outputting the `currencyData` and `localCurrencyData` with NSLog?

Comment: Also, what content-type is the server configured to send for the plist file?

Comment: I don't think the problem is on the server. Because when I tried putting the url in an online md5 tool it gave me the right one. I did not try outputting the data, thanks for that - going to try it and see what it will tell me :)

Comment: Since you're grabbing the file using HTTP, you may want to check that what you receive actually is the same as what is stored.   In particular, line endings and line terminators can be a problem, as well as character encoding if you are using text (XML plist file).   If you are using binary files (encoded plist file), not as much so.   Either way, I'd dump what shows up on the iOS device (or simulator) and diff the file to see that they're identical.   A single byte, such as an additional line terminator, can cause this behavior.

Comment: Finally got it to work. It was partly my stupidity and your answer :D
I wrote the answer below. If you'll write your comment as an answer I will mark it correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, I found out where the problem was.

First thing is, that I am dumb. I was looking at the output and thought that the problem was the remote file, but the wrong hash was given by the local file!

Next thing is, that this was caused by a conversion which Xcode does automatically when compiling the project - it converts the XML Plist file to a Binary Plist file. Thus it has a different MD5 hash.

So the final solution was to convert those remote files to Binary Plists and everything works like a charm!

---

PS: I found a great tool for editing Plists - it is called [PlistEdit Pro](http://www.fatcatsoftware.com/plisteditpro/).
It can do everything you can imagine with the Plists - converts them to binary and vice versa... (I know it can be done in Terminal by plutil, but this is a more convenient solution)

Comment: Did you find out how to make the Mac Terminal yield the same hash as Xcode?